What does a significant PACF and insignificant ACF plot mean about autocorrelation?
I am new to time-series analysis and have been trying to understand how to correctly identify different types of autocorrelation in my seasonal data. I have run a gam and am now looking at the residuals for this.  I have the following ACF and PACF and am struggling to identify what autocorrelation is present. What does it mean if there is no significance in the ACF but significance in the PACF? I cannot find anything on this situation online:

